# How to properly use minitoc after an \addcontentsline statement?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, minitoc

I give a minimal example of my issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}\label{chp:int}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{chp:int}}

\chapter{Chapter1}
\minitoc % No minitoc appears here on the pdf output
\section{Section 1.A}
\section{Section 1.B}

\chapter{Chapter2}
\minitoc % minitoc of chapter 1 appears here
\section{Section 2.A}
\section{Section 2.B}
\end{document}
```

The minitoc of chapter 1 is rendered after the chapter 2. The minitoc of chapter 2 is never rendered. See the following illustration:

[image: Wrong minitoc is rendered!]

If I remove the line `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{chp:int}}`, the bug is fixed. But then `Introduction` does not appear in the table of contents.

How can I use minitoc properly in my case ?

Comment: Shouldn't \dominitoc be after \tableofcontents ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's before or after. There is still the same bug.

Comment: the problem came from:  `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a conflict between table of contents and minitoc.

The solution is to use the command `\adjustmtc` after calling `\tableofcontents`.